# Google privacy page html invalid

Tags: html, validation

Viewing the html source for [Googles Privacy Page](http://www.google.com/intl/en/privacy.html) the header is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Google Privacy Center</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.google.com/css/privacy.css">
  <h1><a href="/"><img src="//www.google.com/intl/en/images/logo_sm.gif" alt="Google"></a> Privacy Center</h1>
```

I noticed there is no **body** tag here or in the footer. Also, no ending **`</html>`**.

Is this valid markup?

Comment: Many of the answers below (including mine) reference the HTML validator on the w3.org website. Just FWIW, beware validating HTML5 with it, the HTML5 support in the validator is still "experimental". If it says you have something wrong, you probably (but not necessarily) do; but it may well miss invalid things...

Comment: That's nuts, the only advantage I can see is the "strip tags on the fly to lose bytes", apart from that is a big chunk-o-mess.

Comment: @Ben: Agreed. Get used to it, though, all sorts of things are optional as of HTML5 (like the `body` tag, the closing `html` tag...).

Comment: Note that its not just HTML5 or HTML4. Those tags have been optional in every version of HTML (not XHTML though). Some people who hand author their code and know this kind of stuff don't believe in typing any more than is absolutely necessary. The open `html` tag is probably only there to hang the `lang` attribute from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 (which is what they're declaring that page as) allows you to omit a lot of stuff. For instance, the `body` tag's start and end tags are both optional, as is the ending `html` tag ([ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags)).

The validator [says it's valid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.google.com/intl/en/privacy.html), but the validator's HTML5 support is also still experimental. YMMV

Answer (score 3):

[The validation page from validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.google.com/intl/en/privacy.html&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0) says it's valid HTML5.

But note that Google doesn't really care if their pages are valid markup or not, as long as they display correctly. Google's main page (google.com) is riddled with invalid markup.

Answer (score 3):

[HTML allows to omit certain start and/or end tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.1):

> Some HTML element types allow authors to omit end tags (e.g., the `P` and `LI` element types). A few element types also allow the start tags to be omitted; for example, `HEAD` and `BODY`. The HTML DTD indicates for each element type whether the start tag and end tag are required.

If you examine a document type definition like the one of [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html), the elements are declared with the [element declarations `<!ELEMENT … >`](http://www.is-thought.co.uk/book/sgml-5.htm#ELEMENT). And within such an element declarations, two characters specify whether the start or end tag of an element can be omitted. See the [definition of `P`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#edef-P) for example:

```
<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->
```

Here the `-` after the element name `P` denotes that the start tag is required and the `O` denotes that the end tag may be omitted. Another example, the [`HEAD` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-HEAD):

```
<!ELEMENT HEAD O O (%head.content;) +(%head.misc;) -- document head -->
```

Here the two `O` specify that both the start and end tag can be omitted.

Omitting both tags on elements is only possible as such elements are implicit in their context. In case of `HEAD`, the content model of the parent [element `HTML`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-HTML) is specified as follows:

```
<!ELEMENT HTML O O (%html.content;)    -- document root element -->
```

Where the parameter entity *html.content* is defined as follows:

```
<!ENTITY % html.content "HEAD, BODY">
```

That means the content model of `HTML` is implicitly defined as `HEAD` followed by `BODY`.

You can take a look at the [index of HTML 4.01 elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html) to see what tags of what elements can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [W3C HTML5 Spec syntax tag omission](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#syntax-tag-omission) :

> A body element's start tag may be
>   omitted if the element is empty, or if
>   the first thing inside the body
>   element is not a space character or a
>   comment, except if the first thing
>   inside the body element is a script or
>   style element. A body element's end
>   tag may be omitted if the body element
>   is not immediately followed by a
>   comment.
>
> An html element's end tag may be
>   omitted if the html element is not
>   immediately followed by a comment.

Funny thing is that the editor of the document is Ian Hickson of Google, Inc.

Answer (score 0):

If you run it through the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fintl%2Fen%2Fprivacy.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) you get that **This document was successfully checked as HTML5!**.

Answer (score 0):

[It is valid HTML5](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fintl%2Fen%2Fprivacy.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

However, it is not XHTML.

Comment: *"However, it is not XHTML."* Nor does it claim to be.

Comment: @T.J.: Correct.  My point is that since it's not XHTML, it doesn't need closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is HTML5

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fintl%2Fen%2Fprivacy.html