# Why doesn't Google close td and tr tags in tables?

Tags: html

Looking at HTML source code of

http://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=983582&startdate=Nov+28,+2000&enddate=Nov+27,+2010&num=200

I see that Google never closes `td` and `tr` tags. There is no `</tr>` no `</td>` in the source.

Why?

```
<tr class=bb>
<th class="bb lm">Date
<th class="rgt bb">Open
<th class="rgt bb">High
<th class="rgt bb">Low
<th class="rgt bb">Close
<th class="rgt bb rm">Volume
<tr>
<td class="lm">Nov 26, 2010
<td class="rgt">11,183.50
<td class="rgt">11,183.50
<td class="rgt">11,067.17
<td class="rgt">11,092.00
<td class="rgt rm">68,396,121
<tr>
```

Is it to make it harder to parse it because XML parser won't be able to read it ? I have remarked that &output=csv is not available for indices (this url won't work: http://www.google.com/finance?q=INDEXDJX:.DJI&output=csv) whereas it is available for stock (http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NASDAQ:GOOG&output=csv will work) so that to get historical data in csv for indices you have to do the parsing job !

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038191/google-homepage-not-valid-html

Comment: No, not a dupe, because this is **valid HTML**.

Comment: Google has multiple versions of their homepage. Each for another browser. They optimize in every possible aspect.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653184/google-privacy-page-html-invalid

Comment: Well, the above example is valid HTML4, but in general the page isn't valid HTML.  According to validator.w3.org, this page has 77 errors.  In this context, the lack of end-tags is probably to save space, and not because of Google's desire to write valid HTML-4-strict.

Comment: @Ken Yes, the goal is to reduce page size, but it is important to note that HTML is not XML and the code about which @RebolTutorial is asking is valid.

Comment: @Ken but it isn't valid XHTML am I wrong (I'm not very proficient at html denomination) ? That is an XML parser can't cope with this ?

Comment: Rebol: It's not XHTML and they never claimed it was.  It wasn't to make it "harder to parse" because every HTML parser under the sun can still handle it just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is HTML4 (and not XML). As pointed out in the [W3 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6):

> #### 11.2.6 Table cells: The TH and TD elements
>
> …
>
> ***Start tag: required, End tag: optional***

Ditto for `tr`:

> #### 11.2.5 Table rows: The TR element
>
> …
>
> ***Start tag: required, End tag: optional***

I believe the intent is to minimize page size by omitting the end tags. They do various additional optimizations which may actually result in invalid HTML, but are handled by browsers in [tagsoup mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup).

Comment: Incidentally, this is another reason **not** to use an XML parser to parse HTML.

Comment: I rather think that it is to prevent parsing than to really economize on bandwidth see my post update.

Answer (score 0):

They do this to save bandwidth. Each byte that comes across the wire is thousands of dollars in Google's book, so why waste extra bytes of data on making readable code. However, they've become less concerned with bandwidth over the past couple years as they've increased their server capacity to God-like proportions, hence the larger logo files (for example, their old logo [here](http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo2.gif) is a roughly 8.5kb gif file that looks like crap, and their current one is a 25+kb PNG), so I suspect they'll eventually come up with a more standards compliant and cleaner home page.